# Настройка wp_link_pages

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Не получается добиться правильного отображения.
Вот сверстанный вариант того как должна выводиться пагинация поста:

```
<div class="post__pag">
  <a href="">1</a>
  <a href="">2</a>
  <a href="">3</a>
</div>
```

Настройка функции `wp_link_pages`:

```
wp_link_pages( array(
     'before'      => '<div class="post__pag">',
     'after'       => '</div>,
     'pagelink'    => '<a href="">%</a>',
     'separator'   => '',
) );
```

А вот результат работы функции:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: 'pagelink'    => '<a href="">%</a>' - и какая же переменная тут является ссылкой? Внутри <a href=""> ничего нет

Answer (score 0):

Параметра `separator` в перечне разрешенных аргументов нет. Но проблема не в этом - `pagelink` надо указывать иначе:

```
wp_link_pages( array(
     'before'      => '<div class="post__pag">',
     'after'       => '</div>',
     'pagelink'    => '%',
) );
```